# Capistrano rails:console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, console, capistrano

My server deployed via Capistrano.

Well I need to enter `rails console` on remote server. I know one of the possible way is *GEM* called `capistrano-console` and all you need to do is to type on local machine `bundle exec cap production rails:console` and it really starting to connect to remote server, but it start to connect with wrong user name.

I mean after `bundle exec cap production rails:console` it start:

```
my_local_user_name@server_ip
```

But I need it to do:

```
my_remote_server_user_name@server_ip
```

Can someone tell why it's happening?

Answer (score 0):

you can set remote user name into role

```
role :app, "my_remote_server_user_name@server_ip"
```

and use that role inside of your command(**on release_roles :app**) or that will be use automatically if you use **on release_roles :all**